# How soon after sealing grout can you use a shower?

Tags: shower, tile, grout

I used Mapei Grout Maximizer to seal the grout. How long does it need to dry before we can use the shower?

Comment: So I am assuming I let the maximimizer dry 2 hours and then test with droplets of water?

Answer (score 4):

Manufacturer directions should state minimum time after sealing for use.  It is important to “test” sealer by sprinkling a few drops of water on the sealed grout to make sure it is repelling water. If the water is spreading out and being absorbed, you need to apply another coat of sealer and allow to dry at least two hours.

Here are the instructions on the Mapei container:
[image: sealer instructions]

Comment: I didn't use a brush on grout sealer. I used their grout additive that lets you grout and seal in one step.

Comment: What you used is a modified grout (added polymer), not a true sealer. It’s akin to shampoo-conditioner-in-one. I’m sure you’re using the shower and that’s fine. Next time you feel ambitious when doing a good bathroom cleaning, after you clean, apply a surface sealer to ensure the integrity of your tile install. Cheers!